# Locked out of MySQL (root)

Tags: mysql, magento, ubuntu

I have created a linked server from Magento MySQL DB to MSSQL Server, but foolishly linked it with Root user and the Root user to the Servers IP.  Now when i try to log into MySQL on putty (Magento server) I can not use root user. I get the error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have tried resetting the user pwd according the Bitnami incstructions: http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/MySQL#How_to_change_the_MySQL_root_password.3f but I am still unable to connect to it locally. The sad part is that I do not have enough rights to create new user from MSSQL and seem to be stuck where I can not get in locally to change any DB rights and I do not have enough rights from the linked server.

Quick re-cap:

> Can not log into mysql from 127.0.0.1 as root
>
> Do not have enough
> rights from xx.xxx.xxx.xx
>
> Reset password is not helping or does not work (I assume I
> did it right)

What to do next? I have all the sudo and su rights for the magento server

Comment: consider copying database's data and remaking it from start.

Comment: It was empty, So dodged a bullet there (huh!) How ever as it is part of bitnami Magento installation I would have to remove the whole installation and taht would be a problem for others. So simple mysql basic database packet installation is out of the question as it has dependencies for the magento store side which peopple are working on

Comment: Remember that SQL Server is not mysql. They are different products.